# Manually trigger mouseover event without allowing the event to propagate

Tags: jquery, mouseover

How can I trigger mouseover event using jQuery just for a specific element, without allowing the event to propagate to the parent controls.

I know how to trigger the event: `$('selector').trigger('mouseover');`

For example I have an `image` inside `tr`. I have hover event handlers for both of them.
I want to manually trigger hover-in event just for the image.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You'll have to change the event handlers to stop propagation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer looking in the examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). 
Here is the code solving my problem:

```
var event = jQuery.Event('<event_name>');
event.stopPropagation();
$('<selector>').trigger(event);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can attach the mouseover as a normal event listener and then do something like this.

```
$("selector").on('mouseover', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

This will stop the event bubbling up to the container elements.
You can then call your trigger as you normally would

```
$('selector').trigger('mouseover');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseenter` or `event.stopPropagation()` like

```
$("img").on('mouseover', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do something
});
```

or

```
$("img").on('mouseenter', function(e){
    // do something
});
```

Read [mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover)

Comment: This does not help me, because I want to trigger event-handlers already attached to this event, no matter when or where.