# Put Hover on some element when mouseover other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="menuHomeCategorias Accesoriosclass">
  <div class="categoryName Accesorios" name="Accesorios">
    <p>Accesorios</p>
  </div>
  <img class="categoriasHome" alt="Categoria" name="Accesorios" src="media/com_hikashop/upload/accesorios.jpg">
</div>
```

and on my css I have this:

```
.categoryName:hover {
  background-color: #BF003E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I need to trigger the `.categoryName:hover` when my pointer is over the img, I have been trying to do this with jquery this way, but it fires a too much recursion message:

```
$('.categoriasHome').bind('mouseover', function(){
    console.log("over");    
    $(".categoryName.Accesorios").mouseover();
});
```

is there someone who can point me into the right direction?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334308/manually-trigger-mouseover-event-without-allowing-the-event-to-propagate

Comment: non jquery solution that you may like: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/fcxA4/

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be easier to add/remove a classname. Like this

```
$('.categoriasHome').hover(function(){
    console.log("over");    
    $(".categoryName.Accesorios").toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

And adjust CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure CSS solution:

html:

```
<div class="menuHomeCategorias Accesoriosclass">
  <img class="categoriasHome" alt="Categoria" name="Accesorios" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  <div class="categoryName Accesorios" name="Accesorios">
    <p>Accesorios</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.categoriasHome:hover + .categoryName{
    background-color:#ee0000;
}
```

here is a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2dJ8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Add this class in the css:
    .newbackground{
      background-color: #BF003E;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }  

$(".categoriasHome").on("mouseover",function(){

    $(this).addClass("newbackground");
});

$(".categoriasHome").on("mouseout",function(){
    $(this).removeClass("newbackground");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using JavaScript:

HTML:

```
  <div class="menuHomeCategorias Accesoriosclass">
      <div class="categoryName Accesorios" Id="Accesorios"  name="Accesorios">
        <p>Accesorios</p>
      </div>
      <img class="categoriasHome" alt="Categoria" name="Accesorios" src="media/com_hikashop/upload/accesorios.jpg" onmouseenter="triggerFunction('Accesorios')" onmouseout="triggerFunctionReverse('Accesorios')">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.categoryName {
  background-color: none;
  color: #000000;
}
.categoryNameHover {
  background-color: #BF003E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function triggerFunction(text){
  document.getElementById(text).setAttribute("class", "categoryNameHover");
}
function triggerFunctionReverse(text){
  document.getElementById(text).setAttribute("class", "categoryName");
}
```

See it at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/diKzH/)